# how i can get the auth.currentuser firebase? in unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

i try to get a firebase value in unity, but the line "auth." donts exist in the context

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;
```

how i can get the auth.currentuser?

this is the link of the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=es-419

Answer (score 2):

solution:

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;
```